# Odds Ratio Between Overlapping Groups

Tags: stata, odds-ratio

Is it inappropriate to use odds ratio for groups that are subset of each other? For example, comparing GPA of female students to GPA of all the students. (This is just an example, not what I am really comparing)

This is a part of a larger project, and my main interest in doing this is to show that the result will be different because of the groups used. And it's based on earlier literatures that I felt the need to show the distinction between the two groups before I proceed with my analysis.

In my opinion, the odds ratio is just a descriptive statistics to compare odds between two groups and I do not really see why it would be wrong. However, Stata did not allow me to do it and so it leads to this discussion.

Main question: why must the groups be dichotomous?

Comment: You can do this but the two samples are not independent, so you can't do any two sample comparisons without including a term in the standard error for the covariance between the parameter estimates (assuming you'd be estimating the difference between two means or log odds ratios).

Comment: Thanks Macro, do you mind adding a little more info about when would I need to include the covariance term?

Comment: You need to do this when the samples are dependent in a way that will result in the two parameter estimates you're comparing being correlated (such as when one sample is a subset of the other).

Comment: Thanks again. By 'when', I meant during what type of tests would I need to do that? Or more specifically, would I need to add anything if I am just interested in the odds ratio between the 2 groups?

Comment: The odds ratio estimates will not be independent and are probably correlated because some of the same data has gone into both estimates. Therefore, treating the statistics as independent and calculating a two-sample statistic comparing the two as if they were independent is not correct - that's all I'm saying.